# Kivy: export_to_png() with an arbitrary scale

Tags: export, kivy, scale

Is there a way to export a widget to png with an arbitrary scale in Kivy?

As far as I understand, now by default the scale of an exported image is 1:1 relative to size of widget that I see on the screen.

But what if I want to export to 1:10 (and get an image 10 times larger)?

Interested in any ideas how this can be done.

Comment: The [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/reference/Image.html) package has a resize method that might be useful.

Comment: I note that I do not want to lose image quality, if you mean the conversion of a small png to a large one. So this option is not suitable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a straight forward method to do the same, but you can fork [export_to_png](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/kivy/uix/widget.py#L605) method of Widget class

Here is a working example:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.graphics import (Canvas, Translate, Fbo, ClearColor,
                           ClearBuffers, Scale)


kv='''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MyWidget:
        id: wgt
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: .1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text: 'enter scale:'
        TextInput:
            id: txtinpt
            text: '2.5'
        Button:
            text: 'Export with new scale'
            on_release: wgt.export_scaled_png('kvwgt.png', image_scale=float(txtinpt.text))

<MyWidget>:
    canvas:
        PushMatrix:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0, 1, .75)
        Ellipse:
            pos: (self.x + self.width // 5, self.y + self.height // 5)
            size: (self.width * 3 // 5, self.height * 3 // 5)
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, .5)
        Rectangle:
            pos: (self.x + self.width // 4, self.y + self.height // 4)
            size: (self.width // 2, self.height // 2)
        Rotate:
            origin:
                self.center
            angle:
                45
    Button:
        text: 'useless child widget\\njust for demonstration'
        center: root.center
        size: (root.width // 2, root.height // 8)
        canvas:
            PopMatrix:

'''

class MyWidget(Widget):

    def export_scaled_png(self, filename, image_scale=1):
        re_size = (self.width * image_scale, 
                self.height * image_scale)

        if self.parent is not None:
            canvas_parent_index = self.parent.canvas.indexof(self.canvas)
            if canvas_parent_index > -1:
                self.parent.canvas.remove(self.canvas)

        fbo = Fbo(size=re_size, with_stencilbuffer=True)

        with fbo:
            ClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0)
            ClearBuffers()
            Scale(image_scale, -image_scale, image_scale)
            Translate(-self.x, -self.y - self.height, 0)

        fbo.add(self.canvas)
        fbo.draw()
        fbo.texture.save(filename, flipped=False)
        fbo.remove(self.canvas)

        if self.parent is not None and canvas_parent_index > -1:
            self.parent.canvas.insert(canvas_parent_index, self.canvas)



runTouchApp(Builder.load_string(kv))
```

Note re_size variable, which in turn passes to Fbo constructor.
And the "***Scale(image_scale, -image_scale, image_scale)***" instruction inside export_scaled_png method.

Comment: Wow, this is really cool! I was sure kivy has such an opportunity.
The only question is: the name of the button becomes fuzzy when exporting, I first thought the reason is that the button widget is rotated ([here's a question I asked in the kivy group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/u0PNYPx5hP0), which is also related to the indistinctness of the button's text display), but the reason is in something else (I set the angle to 0, but the fuzziness remained).
With what it can be connected and is there any way to preserve the quality of text?

Comment: It is actually because of the canvas transformation, first the rotation as on the screen, and then the scaling  of the whole parent widget's framebuffer inside export_scaled_png method.
I believe it shouldn't behave like that, but I can't fix it. I thought of toggling Button._label.mipmap but it doesn't seem to have any effect.